# Prevent iframe from adding entries to browser's history with links inside a pdf document

Tags: iframe

I cannot figure out any way to prevent that behavior with hyperlinks inside a PDF document. Is there any way to achieve this?

We cannot replace iframe with object or embed tag.

@ Jared Farrish: Nope, we want to prevent links in a PDF document being added to browser's history. For example, a PDF document is loaded in an iframe, it also contains links to other pdf documents. When users click on a link, new pdf one is loaded into target iframe, also an entry is added into browser's history. I need to prevent that.

@GolezTrol: Because it's the requirement, if you place it in an embed or object tag, when clicking on a links, your site will be redirected to another new pdf document. I need to load a new pdf document without navigating away the current web page.

Comment: Do you mean that the PDF loaded in the iframe is not entered as a visited link in the browser's history?

Comment: "We cannot replace iframe..."  Why not?

Answer (score 0):

At least in my test using FF4 and Chrome (latest), using a Javascript appendChild did not add it to the history.

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.src = "https://web3.unt.edu/riskman/PDF/UNTSafetyManual__Revised__3-2-06.pdf";
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZML3u/

Comment: Thanks for your solution but it cannot work in my case. 1) First, how can we call your function for every clicking on hyperlinks inside a pdf document? 2) Your solution doesn't work in IE browsers. Is there another way? I also tried iTextSharp but was not successful